# Not SQL Driver Found - but Driver JAR File is implemented

Tags: java, mysql, database, glassfish-3

I connect to a database:

```
          void connectToDataBase(){


      dataManager_ref = new DataBaseConfigurationManager();

       try
       {

            connection = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/dataBase","root",""); 
            System.out.println("Connection successful");
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            System.err.println("Got an exception! "); 
            System.err.println(e.getMessage()); 
        }
     }
```

I implemented a JAR File for the driver:

```
mysql-connector-java-5.1.17-bin.jar
```

and imported it into the servlet

```
import java.sql.DriverManager;
```

this isnt the first time I use this database (tho the first time with Java EE web). This time I get the following exception:

```
No suitable driver found for jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/dataBase
```

The application is running on a glassfish server 3.1, can I even use a database on a mysql server here? Can somebody help please

thanks in advance,
Daniel

Comment: You "implemented" a JAR file? What do you mean by that?

Comment: I add the JAR file in the Libraries folder (under the Libraries node) in the project structure in netbeans

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You sometimes need to load the Driver class explicitly in order for the `DriverManager` to be aware of it.

Try this

```
Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
```

Before you call the `DriverManager`

Answer (score 0):

You can add a CLASSPATH variable in Environmental System variables, and set the path to your connector, path including name of connector.jar.
Also mysql-connector-java-5.1.17-bin.jar is showing some incompatibilities in accessing. it gave me lots of errors, so i had to go bac to 5.0.x versions